# Expand atlaskit Tree parent when mousing over, collapse only when leaving parent and children?

Tags: reactjs

is anyone familiar with Atlassian's `@atlaskit/tree` package? https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/confluence/tree
We have it working well, with parents collapsing and expanding to display the children nodes.
But I'd like it to auto-expand when the user mouseenters the parent, and auto-collapse when it mouseleaves the parent and the children. Expanding is straightforward...but since each node is rendered on its own in the `renderItem` function, I can't figured out how to wrap the parents and all children in a div or something. I need the submenu to stay open until they leave it. Any thoughts?